# Export data frame to shapefile or raster

Tags: r, raster, shapefile

I'm trying to rasterize a data frame in a ESRI shapefile (*.shp), therefore I need to know how to rasterize it or how to create a shapefile  (I already know how to rasterize a shapefile on R).

This data frame is coming from a fortified shapefile that I had to modify (the change numeration in 'PCAr' column and delete the NA values). You can find the code below :

```
df <- df[1:40,]
head(df)
           x        y order  hole piece  id group Id ET_ID ET_Index PCAr
6  -32.33333 40.33333     6 FALSE     1 A10 A10.1  0  1757   26--15    4
7  -32.50000 40.33333     7 FALSE     1 A10 A10.1  0  1757   26--15    4
8  -32.50000 40.50000     8 FALSE     1 A10 A10.1  0  1757   26--15    4
9  -32.33333 40.50000     9 FALSE     1 A10 A10.1  0  1757   26--15    4
10 -32.33333 40.33333    10 FALSE     1 A10 A10.1  0  1757   26--15    4
21 -31.83333 40.33333    21 FALSE     1 A13 A13.1  0  1760   26--18    4

dput(df)    
structure(list(long = c(-32.33333397, -32.5, -32.5, -32.33333397, 
-32.33333397, -31.83333397, -32, -32, -31.83333397, -31.83333397, 
-31.33333397, -31.5, -31.5, -31.33333397, -31.33333397, -33.66666603, 
-33.83333397, -33.83333397, -33.66666603, -33.66666603, -30.16666794, 
-30.33333397, -30.33333397, -30.16666794, -30.16666794, -29.83333588, 
-30.00000191, -30.00000191, -29.83333588, -29.83333588, -29.66666794, 
-29.83333588, -29.83333588, -29.66666794, -29.66666794, -29.50000191, 
-29.66666794, -29.66666794, -29.50000191, -29.50000191), lat = c(40.33333397, 
40.33333397, 40.49999809, 40.49999809, 40.33333397, 40.33333397, 
40.33333397, 40.49999809, 40.49999809, 40.33333397, 40.33333397, 
40.33333397, 40.49999809, 40.49999809, 40.33333397, 40.33333397, 
40.33333397, 40.49999809, 40.49999809, 40.33333397, 40.33333397, 
40.33333397, 40.49999809, 40.49999809, 40.33333397, 40.33333397, 
40.33333397, 40.49999809, 40.49999809, 40.33333397, 40.33333397, 
40.33333397, 40.49999809, 40.49999809, 40.33333397, 40.33333397, 
40.33333397, 40.49999809, 40.49999809, 40.33333397), order = c(6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 
40L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 86L, 87L, 
88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L
), hole = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), piece = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
"28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", 
"39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", 
"50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", 
"61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", 
"72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", 
"83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", 
"94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", "103", 
"104", "105", "106", "107", "108"), class = "factor"), id = c("A10", 
"A10", "A10", "A10", "A10", "A13", "A13", "A13", "A13", "A13", 
"A16", "A16", "A16", "A16", "A16", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", 
"A23", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A23", "A25", "A25", "A25", "A25", 
"A25", "A26", "A26", "A26", "A26", "A26", "A27", "A27", "A27", 
"A27", "A27"), group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), .Label = c("A1.1", "A10.1", "A11.1", 
"A12.1", "A13.1", "A14.1", "A15.1", "A16.1", "A17.1", "A18.1", 
"A19.1", "A2.1", "A20.1", "A21.1", "A22.1", "A23.1", "A24.1", 
"A25.1", "A26.1", "A27.1", "A28.1", "A29.1", "A3.1", "A30.1", 
"A31.1", "A32.1", "A33.1", "A34.1", "A35.1", "A36.1", "A37.1", 
"A38.1", "A39.1", "A4.1", "A40.1", "A41.1", "A42.1", "A43.1", 
"A44.1", "A45.1", "A46.1", "A47.1", "A48.1", "A49.1", "A5.1", 
"A50.1", "A51.1", "A52.1", "A53.1", "A54.1", "A55.1", "A56.1", 
"A57.1", "A58.1", "A59.1", "A6.1", "A60.1", "A61.1", "A7.1", 
"A8.1", "A9.1", "AA1.1", "AA10.1", "AA11.1", "AA12.1", "AA13.1", 
"AA14.1", "AA15.1", "AA16.1", "AA17.1", "AA18.1", "AA19.1", "AA2.1", 
"AA20.1", "AA21.1", "AA22.1", "AA23.1", "AA24.1", "AA25.1", "AA26.1", 
"AA27.1", "AA28.1", "AA29.1", "AA3.1", "AA30.1", "AA31.1", "AA32.1", 
"AA33.1", "AA34.1", "AA35.1", "AA36.1", "AA37.1", "AA38.1", "AA39.1", 
"AA4.1", "AA40.1", "AA41.1", "AA42.1", "AA43.1", "AA44.1", "AA45.1", 
"AA46.1", "AA47.1", "AA48.1", "AA49.1", "AA5.1", "AA50.1", "AA51.1", 
"AA52.1", "AA53.1", "AA54.1", "AA55.1", "AA56.1", "AA57.1", "AA58.1", 
"AA59.1", "AA6.1", "AA60.1", "AA61.1", "AA7.1", "AA8.1", "AA9.1", 
"B1.1", "B10.1", "B11.1", "B12.1", "B13.1", "B14.1", "B15.1", 
"B16.1", "B17.1", "B18.1", "B19.1", "B2.1", "B20.1", "B21.1", 
"B22.1", "B23.1", "B24.1", "B25.1", "B26.1", "B27.1", "B28.1", 
"B29.1", "B3.1", "B30.1", "B31.1", "B32.1", "B33.1", "B34.1", 
"B35.1", "B36.1", "B37.1", "B38.1", "B39.1", "B4.1", "B40.1", 
"B41.1", "B42.1", "B43.1", "B44.1", "B45.1", "B46.1", "B47.1", 
"B48.1", "B49.1", "B5.1", "B50.1", "B51.1", "B52.1", "B53.1", 
"B54.1", "B55.1", "B56.1", "B57.1", "B58.1", "B59.1", "B6.1", 
"B60.1", "B61.1", "B7.1", "B8.1", "B9.1", "C1.1", "C10.1", "C11.1", 
"C12.1", "C13.1", "C14.1", "C15.1", "C16.1", "C17.1", "C18.1", 
"C19.1", "C2.1", "C20.1", "C21.1", "C22.1", "C23.1", "C24.1", 
"C25.1", "C26.1", "C27.1", "C28.1", "C29.1", "C3.1", "C30.1", 
"C31.1", "C32.1", "C33.1", "C34.1", "C35.1", "C36.1", "C37.1", 
"C38.1", "C39.1", "C4.1", "C40.1", "C41.1", "C42.1", "C43.1", 
"C44.1", "C45.1", "C46.1", "C47.1", "C48.1", "C49.1", "C5.1", 
"C50.1", "C51.1", "C52.1", "C53.1", "C54.1", "C55.1", "C56.1", 
"C57.1", "C58.1", "C59.1", "C6.1", "C60.1", "C61.1", "C7.1", 
"C8.1", "C9.1", "D1.1", "D10.1", "D11.1", "D12.1", "D13.1", "D14.1", 
"D15.1", "D16.1", "D17.1", "D18.1", "D19.1", "D2.1", "D20.1", 
"D21.1", "D22.1", "D23.1", "D24.1", "D25.1", "D26.1", "D27.1", 
"D28.1", "D29.1", "D3.1", "D30.1", "D31.1", "D32.1", "D33.1", 
"D34.1", "D35.1", "D36.1", "D37.1", "D38.1", "D39.1", "D4.1", 
"D40.1", "D41.1", "D42.1", "D43.1", "D44.1", "D45.1", "D46.1", 
"D47.1", "D48.1", "D49.1", "D5.1", "D50.1", "D51.1", "D52.1", 
"D53.1", "D54.1", "D55.1", "D56.1", "D57.1", "D58.1", "D59.1", 
"D6.1", "D60.1", "D61.1", "D7.1", "D8.1", "D9.1", "E1.1", "E10.1", 
"E11.1", "E12.1", "E13.1", "E14.1", "E15.1", "E16.1", "E17.1", 
"E18.1", "E18.2", "E18.3", "E18.4", "E18.5", "E18.6", "E18.7", 
"E18.8", "E18.9", "E18.10", "E18.11", "E18.12", "E18.13", "E18.14", 
"E18.15", "E18.16", "E18.17", "E18.18", "E18.19", "E18.20", "E18.21", 
"E18.22", "E18.23", "E18.24", "E18.25", "E18.26", "E18.27", "E18.28", 
"E18.29", "E18.30", "E18.31", "E18.32", "E18.33", "E18.34", "E18.35", 
"E18.36", "E18.37", "E18.38", "E18.39", "E18.40", "E18.41", "E18.42", 
"E18.43", "E18.44", "E18.45", "E18.46", "E18.47", "E18.48", "E18.49", 
"E18.50", "E18.51", "E18.52", "E18.53", "E18.54", "E18.55", "E18.56", 
"E18.57", "E18.58", "E18.59", "E19.1", "E2.1", "E20.1", "E21.1", 
"E22.1", "E23.1", "E24.1", "E25.1", "E26.1", "E27.1", "E28.1", 
"E29.1", "E3.1", "E30.1", "E31.1", "E32.1", "E33.1", "E34.1", 
"E35.1", "E36.1", "E37.1", "E38.1", "E39.1", "E4.1", "E40.1", 
"E41.1", "E42.1", "E43.1", "E44.1", "E45.1", "E46.1", "E47.1", 
"E48.1", "E49.1", "E5.1", "E50.1", "E51.1", "E52.1", "E53.1", 
"E54.1", "E55.1", "E56.1", "E57.1", "E58.1", "E59.1", "E6.1", 
"E60.1", "E61.1", "E7.1", "E8.1", "E9.1", "F1.1", "F10.1", "F11.1", 
"F12.1", "F13.1", "F14.1", "F15.1", "F16.1", "F17.1", "F17.2", 
"F17.3", "F17.4", "F17.5", "F17.6", "F17.7", "F17.8", "F17.9", 
"F17.10", "F17.11", "F17.12", "F17.13", "F17.14", "F17.15", "F17.16", 
"F17.17", "F17.18", "F17.19", "F17.20", "F17.21", "F17.22", "F17.23", 
"F17.24", "F17.25", "F17.26", "F17.27", "F17.28", "F17.29", "F17.30", 
"F17.31", "F17.32", "F17.33", "F17.34", "F17.35", "F17.36", "F17.37", 
"F17.38", "F17.39", "F17.40", "F17.41", "F17.42", "F17.43", "F17.44", 
"F17.45", "F17.46", "F17.47", "F17.48", "F17.49", "F17.50", "F17.51", 
"F17.52", "F17.53", "F17.54", "F17.55", "F17.56", "F17.57", "F17.58", 
"F17.59", "F17.60", "F17.61", "F17.62", "F17.63", "F17.64", "F17.65", 
"F17.66", "F17.67", "F17.68", "F17.69", "F17.70", "F17.71", "F17.72", 
"F17.73", "F17.74", "F17.75", "F17.76", "F17.77", "F17.78", "F17.79", 
"F17.80", "F17.81", "F17.82", "F17.83", "F17.84", "F17.85", "F17.86", 
"F17.87", "F18.1", "F18.2", "F18.3", "F18.4", "F18.5", "F18.6", 
"F18.7", "F18.8", "F18.9", "F18.10", "F18.11", "F18.12", "F18.13", 
"F18.14", "F18.15", "F18.16", "F18.17", "F19.1", "F2.1", "F20.1", 
"F21.1", "F22.1", "F23.1", "F24.1", "F25.1", "F26.1", "F27.1", 
"F28.1", "F29.1", "F3.1", "F30.1", "F31.1", "F32.1", "F33.1", 
"F34.1", "F35.1", "F36.1", "F37.1", "F38.1", "F39.1", "F4.1", 
"F40.1", "F41.1", "F42.1", "F43.1", "F44.1", "F45.1", "F46.1", 
"F47.1", "F48.1", "F49.1", "F5.1", "F50.1", "F51.1", "F52.1", 
"F53.1", "F54.1", "F55.1", "F56.1", "F57.1", "F58.1", "F59.1", 
"F6.1", "F60.1", "F61.1", "F7.1", "F8.1", "F9.1", "G1.1", "G10.1", 
"G11.1", "G12.1", "G13.1", "G14.1", "G15.1", "G16.1", "G17.1", 
"G17.2", "G17.3", "G17.4", "G17.5", "G17.6", "G17.7", "G17.8", 
"G17.9", "G17.10", "G17.11", "G17.12", "G17.13", "G17.14", "G17.15", 
"G17.16", "G17.17", "G17.18", "G17.19", "G17.20", "G17.21", "G17.22", 
"G17.23", "G17.24", "G17.25", "G17.26", "G17.27", "G17.28", "G17.29", 
"G17.30", "G17.31", "G17.32", "G17.33", "G17.34", "G17.35", "G17.36", 
"G17.37", "G17.38", "G17.39", "G17.40", "G17.41", "G17.42", "G17.43", 
"G17.44", "G17.45", "G17.46", "G17.47", "G17.48", "G17.49", "G17.50", 
"G17.51", "G17.52", "G17.53", "G17.54", "G17.55", "G17.56", "G17.57", 
"G17.58", "G17.59", "G17.60", "G17.61", "G17.62", "G17.63", "G17.64", 
"G17.65", "G17.66", "G17.67", "G17.68", "G17.69", "G17.70", "G17.71", 
"G17.72", "G17.73", "G17.74", "G17.75", "G17.76", "G17.77", "G17.78", 
"G17.79", "G17.80", "G17.81", "G17.82", "G17.83", "G17.84", "G17.85", 
"G18.1", "G18.2", "G18.3", "G18.4", "G18.5", "G18.6", "G18.7", 
"G18.8", "G18.9", "G18.10", "G18.11", "G18.12", "G18.13", "G18.14", 
"G18.15", "G18.16", "G18.17", "G18.18", "G18.19", "G18.20", "G18.21", 
"G18.22", "G18.23", "G18.24", "G18.25", "G18.26", "G18.27", "G18.28", 
"G18.29", "G18.30", "G18.31", "G18.32", "G18.33", "G18.34", "G18.35", 
"G18.36", "G18.37", "G18.38", "G18.39", "G18.40", "G18.41", "G18.42", 
"G18.43", "G18.44", "G18.45", "G18.46", "G18.47", "G18.48", "G18.49", 
"G18.50", "G18.51", "G18.52", "G18.53", "G18.54", "G18.55", "G18.56", 
"G18.57", "G18.58", "G18.59", "G18.60", "G18.61", "G18.62", "G18.63", 
"G18.64", "G18.65", "G18.66", "G18.67", "G18.68", "G18.69", "G18.70", 
"G18.71", "G18.72", "G18.73", "G18.74", "G18.75", "G18.76", "G18.77", 
"G18.78", "G18.79", "G18.80", "G18.81", "G18.82", "G18.83", "G18.84", 
"G18.85", "G18.86", "G18.87", "G18.88", "G18.89", "G18.90", "G18.91", 
"G18.92", "G18.93", "G18.94", "G18.95", "G18.96", "G18.97", "G18.98", 
"G18.99", "G18.100", "G18.101", "G18.102", "G18.103", "G18.104", 
"G18.105", "G18.106", "G18.107", "G18.108", "G19.1", "G2.1", 
"G20.1", "G21.1", "G22.1", "G23.1", "G24.1", "G25.1", "G26.1", 
"G27.1", "G28.1", "G29.1", "G3.1", "G30.1", "G31.1", "G32.1", 
"G33.1", "G34.1", "G35.1", "G36.1", "G37.1", "G38.1", "G39.1", 
"G4.1", "G40.1", "G41.1", "G42.1", "G43.1", "G44.1", "G45.1", 
"G46.1", "G47.1", "G48.1", "G49.1", "G5.1", "G50.1", "G51.1", 
"G52.1", "G53.1", "G54.1", "G55.1", "G56.1", "G57.1", "G58.1", 
"G59.1", "G6.1", "G60.1", "G61.1", "G7.1", "G8.1", "G9.1", "H1.1", 
"H10.1", "H11.1", "H12.1", "H13.1", "H14.1", "H15.1", "H16.1", 
"H17.1", "H18.1", "H19.1", "H2.1", "H20.1", "H21.1", "H22.1", 
"H23.1", "H24.1", "H25.1", "H26.1", "H27.1", "H28.1", "H29.1", 
"H3.1", "H30.1", "H31.1", "H32.1", "H33.1", "H34.1", "H35.1", 
"H36.1", "H37.1", "H38.1", "H39.1", "H4.1", "H40.1", "H41.1", 
"H42.1", "H43.1", "H44.1", "H45.1", "H46.1", "H47.1", "H48.1", 
"H49.1", "H5.1", "H50.1", "H51.1", "H52.1", "H53.1", "H54.1", 
"H55.1", "H56.1", "H57.1", "H58.1", "H59.1", "H6.1", "H60.1", 
"H61.1", "H7.1", "H8.1", "H9.1", "I1.1", "I10.1", "I11.1", "I12.1", 
"I13.1", "I14.1", "I15.1", "I16.1", "I17.1", "I18.1", "I19.1", 
"I2.1", "I20.1", "I21.1", "I22.1", "I23.1", "I24.1", "I25.1", 
"I26.1", "I27.1", "I28.1", "I29.1", "I3.1", "I30.1", "I31.1", 
"I32.1", "I33.1", "I34.1", "I35.1", "I36.1", "I36.2", "I36.3", 
"I36.4", "I36.5", "I36.6", "I36.7", "I36.8", "I36.9", "I36.10", 
"I37.1", "I37.2", "I37.3", "I37.4", "I37.5", "I37.6", "I37.7", 
"I37.8", "I38.1", "I39.1", "I4.1", "I40.1", "I41.1", "I42.1", 
"I43.1", "I44.1", "I45.1", "I46.1", "I47.1", "I48.1", "I49.1", 
"I5.1", "I50.1", "I51.1", "I52.1", "I53.1", "I54.1", "I55.1", 
"I56.1", "I57.1", "I58.1", "I59.1", "I6.1", "I60.1", "I61.1", 
"I7.1", "I8.1", "I9.1", "J1.1", "J10.1", "J11.1", "J12.1", "J13.1", 
"J14.1", "J15.1", "J16.1", "J17.1", "J18.1", "J19.1", "J2.1", 
"J20.1", "J21.1", "J22.1", "J23.1", "J24.1", "J25.1", "J26.1", 
"J27.1", "J28.1", "J29.1", "J3.1", "J30.1", "J31.1", "J32.1", 
"J33.1", "J34.1", "J35.1", "J36.1", "J37.1", "J38.1", "J39.1", 
"J4.1", "J40.1", "J41.1", "J42.1", "J43.1", "J44.1", "J45.1", 
"J46.1", "J47.1", "J48.1", "J49.1", "J5.1", "J50.1", "J51.1", 
"J52.1", "J53.1", "J54.1", "J55.1", "J56.1", "J57.1", "J58.1", 
"J59.1", "J6.1", "J60.1", "J61.1", "J7.1", "J8.1", "J9.1", "K1.1", 
"K10.1", "K11.1", "K12.1", "K13.1", "K14.1", "K15.1", "K16.1", 
"K17.1", "K18.1", "K19.1", "K2.1", "K20.1", "K21.1", "K22.1", 
"K23.1", "K24.1", "K25.1", "K26.1", "K27.1", "K28.1", "K29.1", 
"K3.1", "K30.1", "K31.1", "K32.1", "K33.1", "K34.1", "K35.1", 
"K35.2", "K35.3", "K35.4", "K35.5", "K35.6", "K35.7", "K35.8", 
"K35.9", "K35.10", "K35.11", "K35.12", "K35.13", "K35.14", "K36.1", 
"K37.1", "K38.1", "K39.1", "K4.1", "K40.1", "K41.1", "K41.2", 
"K41.3", "K42.1", "K42.2", "K43.1", "K44.1", "K45.1", "K46.1", 
"K47.1", "K48.1", "K49.1", "K5.1", "K50.1", "K51.1", "K52.1", 
"K53.1", "K54.1", "K55.1", "K56.1", "K57.1", "K58.1", "K59.1", 
"K6.1", "K60.1", "K61.1", "K7.1", "K8.1", "K9.1", "L1.1", "L10.1", 
"L11.1", "L12.1", "L13.1", "L14.1", "L15.1", "L16.1", "L17.1", 
"L18.1", "L19.1", "L2.1", "L20.1", "L21.1", "L22.1", "L23.1", 
"L24.1", "L25.1", "L26.1", "L27.1", "L28.1", "L29.1", "L3.1", 
"L30.1", "L31.1", "L32.1", "L32.2", "L32.3", "L32.4", "L32.5", 
"L33.1", "L33.2", "L33.3", "L33.4", "L33.5", "L33.6", "L33.7", 
"L34.1", "L35.1", "L36.1", "L36.2", "L36.3", "L36.4", "L36.5", 
"L36.6", "L36.7", "L37.1", "L37.2", "L37.3", "L37.4", "L38.1", 
"L38.2", "L38.3", "L39.1", "L4.1", "L40.1", "L41.1", "L41.2", 
"L41.3", "L41.4", "L41.5", "L41.6", "L41.7", "L41.8", "L41.9", 
"L41.10", "L41.11", "L41.12", "L41.13", "L41.14", "L41.15", "L41.16", 
"L41.17", "L41.18", "L41.19", "L41.20", "L41.21", "L41.22", "L41.23", 
"L41.24", "L41.25", "L41.26", "L41.27", "L41.28", "L41.29", "L42.1", 
"L42.2", "L42.3", "L42.4", "L42.5", "L42.6", "L42.7", "L42.8", 
"L42.9", "L42.10", "L42.11", "L42.12", "L42.13", "L42.14", "L42.15", 
"L43.1", "L44.1", "L45.1", "L46.1", "L47.1", "L48.1", "L49.1", 
"L5.1", "L50.1", "L51.1", "L52.1", "L53.1", "L54.1", "L55.1", 
"L56.1", "L57.1", "L58.1", "L59.1", "L6.1", "L60.1", "L61.1", 
"L7.1", "L8.1", "L9.1", "M1.1", "M10.1", "M11.1", "M12.1", "M13.1", 
"M14.1", "M15.1", "M16.1", "M17.1", "M18.1", "M19.1", "M2.1", 
"M20.1", "M21.1", "M22.1", "M23.1", "M24.1", "M25.1", "M26.1", 
"M27.1", "M28.1", "M29.1", "M3.1", "M30.1", "M31.1", "M32.1", 
"M33.1", "M33.2", "M34.1", "M34.2", "M34.3", "M34.4", "M34.5", 
"M35.1", "M35.2", "M35.3", "M35.4", "M35.5", "M35.6", "M35.7", 
"M35.8", "M35.9", "M35.10", "M35.11", "M35.12", "M35.13", "M35.14", 
"M35.15", "M35.16", "M35.17", "M35.18", "M35.19", "M35.20", "M36.1", 
"M36.2", "M36.3", "M36.4", "M36.5", "M36.6", "M37.1", "M38.1", 
"M39.1", "M4.1", "M40.1", "M41.1", "M42.1", "M43.1", "M44.1", 
"M45.1", "M46.1", "M47.1", "M48.1", "M49.1", "M5.1", "M50.1", 
"M51.1", "M52.1", "M53.1", "M54.1", "M55.1", "M56.1", "M57.1", 
"M58.1", "M59.1", "M6.1", "M60.1", "M61.1", "M7.1", "M8.1", "M9.1", 
"N1.1", "N10.1", "N11.1", "N12.1", "N13.1", "N14.1", "N15.1", 
"N16.1", "N17.1", "N18.1", "N19.1", "N2.1", "N20.1", "N21.1", 
"N22.1", "N23.1", "N24.1", "N25.1", "N26.1", "N27.1", "N28.1", 
"N29.1", "N3.1", "N30.1", "N31.1", "N32.1", "N33.1", "N34.1", 
"N35.1", "N36.1", "N37.1", "N38.1", "N39.1", "N4.1", "N40.1", 
"N41.1", "N42.1", "N43.1", "N44.1", "N45.1", "N46.1", "N47.1", 
"N48.1", "N49.1", "N5.1", "N50.1", "N51.1", "N52.1", "N53.1", 
"N54.1", "N55.1", "N56.1", "N57.1", "N58.1", "N59.1", "N6.1", 
"N60.1", "N61.1", "N7.1", "N8.1", "N9.1", "O1.1", "O10.1", "O11.1", 
"O12.1", "O13.1", "O14.1", "O15.1", "O16.1", "O17.1", "O18.1", 
"O19.1", "O2.1", "O20.1", "O21.1", "O22.1", "O23.1", "O24.1", 
"O25.1", "O26.1", "O27.1", "O28.1", "O29.1", "O3.1", "O30.1", 
"O31.1", "O32.1", "O33.1", "O34.1", "O35.1", "O36.1", "O37.1", 
"O38.1", "O39.1", "O4.1", "O40.1", "O41.1", "O42.1", "O43.1", 
"O44.1", "O45.1", "O46.1", "O47.1", "O48.1", "O49.1", "O5.1", 
"O50.1", "O51.1", "O52.1", "O53.1", "O54.1", "O55.1", "O56.1", 
"O57.1", "O58.1", "O59.1", "O6.1", "O60.1", "O61.1", "O7.1", 
"O8.1", "O9.1", "P1.1", "P10.1", "P11.1", "P12.1", "P13.1", "P14.1", 
"P15.1", "P16.1", "P17.1", "P18.1", "P19.1", "P2.1", "P20.1", 
"P21.1", "P22.1", "P23.1", "P24.1", "P25.1", "P26.1", "P27.1", 
"P28.1", "P29.1", "P3.1", "P30.1", "P31.1", "P32.1", "P33.1", 
"P34.1", "P35.1", "P36.1", "P37.1", "P38.1", "P39.1", "P4.1", 
"P40.1", "P41.1", "P42.1", "P43.1", "P44.1", "P45.1", "P46.1", 
"P47.1", "P48.1", "P49.1", "P49.2", "P49.3", "P49.4", "P49.5", 
"P49.6", "P49.7", "P49.8", "P49.9", "P49.10", "P49.11", "P49.12", 
"P5.1", "P50.1", "P50.2", "P50.3", "P50.4", "P50.5", "P50.6", 
"P50.7", "P50.8", "P50.9", "P50.10", "P50.11", "P50.12", "P50.13", 
"P50.14", "P50.15", "P50.16", "P50.17", "P50.18", "P50.19", "P50.20", 
"P50.21", "P50.22", "P50.23", "P50.24", "P50.25", "P50.26", "P50.27", 
"P50.28", "P50.29", "P50.30", "P50.31", "P50.32", "P51.1", "P52.1", 
"P52.2", "P52.3", "P52.4", "P52.5", "P52.6", "P52.7", "P52.8", 
"P52.9", "P52.10", "P52.11", "P52.12", "P52.13", "P52.14", "P52.15", 
"P52.16", "P52.17", "P52.18", "P52.19", "P52.20", "P52.21", "P52.22", 
"P52.23", "P52.24", "P52.25", "P52.26", "P52.27", "P52.28", "P52.29", 
"P52.30", "P52.31", "P52.32", "P52.33", "P52.34", "P52.35", "P52.36", 
"P52.37", "P52.38", "P52.39", "P52.40", "P52.41", "P52.42", "P52.43", 
"P53.1", "P53.2", "P53.3", "P53.4", "P54.1", "P55.1", "P56.1", 
"P57.1", "P58.1", "P59.1", "P6.1", "P60.1", "P61.1", "P7.1", 
"P8.1", "P9.1", "Q1.1", "Q10.1", "Q11.1", "Q12.1", "Q13.1", "Q14.1", 
"Q15.1", "Q16.1", "Q17.1", "Q18.1", "Q19.1", "Q2.1", "Q20.1", 
"Q21.1", "Q22.1", "Q23.1", "Q24.1", "Q25.1", "Q26.1", "Q27.1", 
"Q28.1", "Q29.1", "Q3.1", "Q30.1", "Q31.1", "Q32.1", "Q33.1", 
"Q34.1", "Q35.1", "Q36.1", "Q37.1", "Q38.1", "Q39.1", "Q4.1", 
"Q40.1", "Q41.1", "Q42.1", "Q43.1", "Q44.1", "Q45.1", "Q46.1", 
"Q47.1", "Q48.1", "Q49.1", "Q5.1", "Q50.1", "Q50.2", "Q50.3", 
"Q51.1", "Q51.2", "Q51.3", "Q51.4", "Q51.5", "Q51.6", "Q52.1", 
"Q52.2", "Q52.3", "Q52.4", "Q52.5", "Q52.6", "Q52.7", "Q52.8", 
"Q52.9", "Q52.10", "Q52.11", "Q52.12", "Q52.13", "Q52.14", "Q52.15", 
"Q52.16", "Q52.17", "Q52.18", "Q52.19", "Q52.20", "Q52.21", "Q53.1", 
"Q54.1", "Q55.1", "Q56.1", "Q57.1", "Q58.1", "Q59.1", "Q6.1", 
"Q60.1", "Q61.1", "Q7.1", "Q8.1", "Q9.1", "R1.1", "R10.1", "R11.1", 
"R12.1", "R13.1", "R14.1", "R15.1", "R16.1", "R17.1", "R18.1", 
"R19.1", "R2.1", "R20.1", "R21.1", "R22.1", "R23.1", "R24.1", 
"R25.1", "R26.1", "R27.1", "R28.1", "R29.1", "R3.1", "R30.1", 
"R31.1", "R32.1", "R33.1", "R34.1", "R35.1", "R36.1", "R37.1", 
"R38.1", "R39.1", "R4.1", "R40.1", "R41.1", "R42.1", "R43.1", 
"R44.1", "R45.1", "R46.1", "R47.1", "R48.1", "R49.1", "R5.1", 
"R50.1", "R51.1", "R52.1", "R53.1", "R54.1", "R55.1", "R56.1", 
"R57.1", "R58.1", "R59.1", "R6.1", "R60.1", "R61.1", "R7.1", 
"R8.1", "R9.1", "S1.1", "S10.1", "S11.1", "S12.1", "S13.1", "S14.1", 
"S15.1", "S16.1", "S17.1", "S18.1", "S19.1", "S2.1", "S20.1", 
"S21.1", "S22.1", "S23.1", "S24.1", "S25.1", "S26.1", "S27.1", 
"S28.1", "S29.1", "S3.1", "S30.1", "S31.1", "S32.1", "S33.1", 
"S34.1", "S35.1", "S36.1", "S37.1", "S38.1", "S39.1", "S4.1", 
"S40.1", "S41.1", "S42.1", "S43.1", "S44.1", "S45.1", "S46.1", 
"S47.1", "S48.1", "S49.1", "S5.1", "S50.1", "S51.1", "S52.1", 
"S53.1", "S54.1", "S55.1", "S56.1", "S57.1", "S58.1", "S59.1", 
"S6.1", "S60.1", "S61.1", "S7.1", "S8.1", "S9.1", "T1.1", "T10.1", 
"T11.1", "T12.1", "T13.1", "T14.1", "T15.1", "T16.1", "T17.1", 
"T18.1", "T19.1", "T2.1", "T20.1", "T21.1", "T22.1", "T23.1", 
"T24.1", "T25.1", "T26.1", "T27.1", "T28.1", "T29.1", "T3.1", 
"T30.1", "T31.1", "T32.1", "T33.1", "T34.1", "T35.1", "T36.1", 
"T37.1", "T38.1", "T39.1", "T4.1", "T40.1", "T41.1", "T42.1", 
"T43.1", "T44.1", "T45.1", "T46.1", "T47.1", "T48.1", "T49.1", 
"T5.1", "T50.1", "T51.1", "T52.1", "T53.1", "T54.1", "T55.1", 
"T56.1", "T56.2", "T56.3", "T56.4", "T56.5", "T56.6", "T56.7", 
"T56.8", "T56.9", "T56.10", "T56.11", "T56.12", "T56.13", "T56.14", 
"T56.15", "T56.16", "T56.17", "T56.18", "T56.19", "T56.20", "T56.21", 
"T56.22", "T56.23", "T56.24", "T56.25", "T56.26", "T56.27", "T56.28", 
"T56.29", "T56.30", "T56.31", "T56.32", "T57.1", "T58.1", "T59.1", 
"T6.1", "T60.1", "T61.1", "T7.1", "T8.1", "T9.1", "U1.1", "U10.1", 
"U11.1", "U12.1", "U13.1", "U14.1", "U15.1", "U16.1", "U17.1", 
"U18.1", "U19.1", "U2.1", "U20.1", "U21.1", "U22.1", "U23.1", 
"U24.1", "U25.1", "U26.1", "U27.1", "U28.1", "U29.1", "U3.1", 
"U30.1", "U31.1", "U32.1", "U33.1", "U34.1", "U35.1", "U36.1", 
"U37.1", "U38.1", "U39.1", "U4.1", "U40.1", "U41.1", "U42.1", 
"U43.1", "U44.1", "U45.1", "U46.1", "U47.1", "U48.1", "U49.1", 
"U5.1", "U50.1", "U51.1", "U52.1", "U53.1", "U53.2", "U54.1", 
"U54.2", "U54.3", "U54.4", "U54.5", "U54.6", "U54.7", "U54.8", 
"U54.9", "U54.10", "U54.11", "U54.12", "U54.13", "U54.14", "U54.15", 
"U54.16", "U54.17", "U55.1", "U56.1", "U57.1", "U58.1", "U59.1", 
"U6.1", "U60.1", "U61.1", "U7.1", "U8.1", "U9.1", "V1.1", "V10.1", 
"V11.1", "V12.1", "V13.1", "V14.1", "V15.1", "V16.1", "V17.1", 
"V18.1", "V19.1", "V2.1", "V20.1", "V21.1", "V22.1", "V23.1", 
"V24.1", "V25.1", "V26.1", "V27.1", "V28.1", "V29.1", "V3.1", 
"V30.1", "V31.1", "V32.1", "V33.1", "V34.1", "V35.1", "V36.1", 
"V37.1", "V38.1", "V39.1", "V4.1", "V40.1", "V41.1", "V42.1", 
"V43.1", "V44.1", "V45.1", "V46.1", "V47.1", "V48.1", "V49.1", 
"V5.1", "V50.1", "V51.1", "V52.1", "V53.1", "V53.2", "V53.3", 
"V54.1", "V54.2", "V54.3", "V54.4", "V54.5", "V54.6", "V54.7", 
"V55.1", "V56.1", "V57.1", "V58.1", "V59.1", "V6.1", "V60.1", 
"V61.1", "V7.1", "V8.1", "V9.1", "W1.1", "W10.1", "W11.1", "W12.1", 
"W13.1", "W14.1", "W15.1", "W16.1", "W17.1", "W18.1", "W19.1", 
"W2.1", "W20.1", "W21.1", "W22.1", "W23.1", "W24.1", "W25.1", 
"W26.1", "W27.1", "W28.1", "W29.1", "W3.1", "W30.1", "W31.1", 
"W32.1", "W33.1", "W34.1", "W35.1", "W36.1", "W37.1", "W38.1", 
"W39.1", "W4.1", "W40.1", "W41.1", "W42.1", "W43.1", "W44.1", 
"W45.1", "W46.1", "W47.1", "W48.1", "W49.1", "W5.1", "W50.1", 
"W51.1", "W52.1", "W53.1", "W54.1", "W55.1", "W56.1", "W57.1", 
"W58.1", "W59.1", "W6.1", "W60.1", "W61.1", "W7.1", "W8.1", "W9.1", 
"X1.1", "X1.2", "X10.1", "X10.2", "X11.1", "X11.2", "X12.1", 
"X12.2", "X13.1", "X13.2", "X14.1", "X14.2", "X15.1", "X15.2", 
"X16.1", "X16.2", "X17.1", "X17.2", "X18.1", "X18.2", "X19.1", 
"X19.2", "X2.1", "X2.2", "X20.1", "X20.2", "X21.1", "X21.2", 
"X22.1", "X22.2", "X23.1", "X23.2", "X24.1", "X24.2", "X25.1", 
"X25.2", "X26.1", "X26.2", "X27.1", "X27.2", "X28.1", "X28.2", 
"X29.1", "X29.2", "X3.1", "X3.2", "X30.1", "X30.2", "X31.1", 
"X31.2", "X32.1", "X32.2", "X33.1", "X33.2", "X34.1", "X34.2", 
"X35.1", "X35.2", "X36.1", "X36.2", "X37.1", "X37.2", "X38.1", 
"X38.2", "X39.1", "X39.2", "X4.1", "X4.2", "X40.1", "X40.2", 
"X41.1", "X41.2", "X42.1", "X42.2", "X43.1", "X43.2", "X44.1", 
"X44.2", "X45.1", "X45.2", "X46.1", "X46.2", "X47.1", "X47.2", 
"X48.1", "X48.2", "X49.1", "X49.2", "X5.1", "X5.2", "X50.1", 
"X50.2", "X51.1", "X51.2", "X52.1", "X52.2", "X53.1", "X53.2", 
"X54.1", "X54.2", "X55.1", "X55.2", "X56.1", "X56.2", "X57.1", 
"X57.2", "X58.1", "X58.2", "X59.1", "X59.2", "X6.1", "X6.2", 
"X60.1", "X60.2", "X61.1", "X61.2", "X7.1", "X7.2", "X8.1", "X8.2", 
"X9.1", "X9.2", "Y1.1", "Y10.1", "Y11.1", "Y12.1", "Y13.1", "Y14.1", 
"Y15.1", "Y16.1", "Y17.1", "Y18.1", "Y19.1", "Y2.1", "Y20.1", 
"Y21.1", "Y22.1", "Y23.1", "Y24.1", "Y25.1", "Y26.1", "Y27.1", 
"Y28.1", "Y29.1", "Y3.1", "Y30.1", "Y31.1", "Y32.1", "Y33.1", 
"Y34.1", "Y35.1", "Y36.1", "Y37.1", "Y38.1", "Y39.1", "Y4.1", 
"Y40.1", "Y41.1", "Y42.1", "Y43.1", "Y44.1", "Y45.1", "Y46.1", 
"Y47.1", "Y48.1", "Y49.1", "Y5.1", "Y50.1", "Y51.1", "Y52.1", 
"Y53.1", "Y54.1", "Y55.1", "Y56.1", "Y57.1", "Y58.1", "Y59.1", 
"Y6.1", "Y60.1", "Y61.1", "Y7.1", "Y8.1", "Y9.1", "Z1.1", "Z10.1", 
"Z11.1", "Z12.1", "Z13.1", "Z14.1", "Z15.1", "Z16.1", "Z17.1", 
"Z18.1", "Z19.1", "Z2.1", "Z20.1", "Z21.1", "Z22.1", "Z23.1", 
"Z24.1", "Z25.1", "Z26.1", "Z27.1", "Z28.1", "Z29.1", "Z3.1", 
"Z30.1", "Z31.1", "Z32.1", "Z33.1", "Z34.1", "Z35.1", "Z36.1", 
"Z37.1", "Z38.1", "Z39.1", "Z4.1", "Z40.1", "Z41.1", "Z42.1", 
"Z43.1", "Z44.1", "Z45.1", "Z46.1", "Z47.1", "Z48.1", "Z49.1", 
"Z5.1", "Z50.1", "Z51.1", "Z52.1", "Z53.1", "Z54.1", "Z55.1", 
"Z56.1", "Z57.1", "Z58.1", "Z59.1", "Z6.1", "Z60.1", "Z61.1", 
"Z7.1", "Z8.1", "Z9.1"), class = "factor"), PCAr = c(4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 
40L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 86L, 87L, 
88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L
))
```

Comment: You should not "fortify to modify (the change numeration in 'PCAr' column and delete the NA values)." so you are asking the wrong question. Also, in R you would have an object of a particular class, not a shapefile.

Comment: And so, how is it possible to modify the data directly in the  SpatialPolygonsDataFrame@data?